# XML::LibXML findvalue for an attribute with a namespace prefix

Tags: xml, perl, xml-libxml

I am having some issues using
[`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML)
with namespaces. I have parsed files with namespaces before but this one is a bit different because it is defined with `xlmns:abc` rather then just `xlmns`.

I can't extract the `893` value of `abc:id` from this element

```
<element name='THEFIELD' type='string' abc:id='893' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'>
```

Sample data

```xml
<schema
    xmlns:abc="http://www.example.com/schemas/abc"
    targetNamespace="http://example.com/schemas/product"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <TheType name='MyName'>
    <sequence>
      <element name='THEFIELD' type='string' abc:id='893' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'>
        <annotation><documentation>Identifier - Realtime</documentation></annotation>
      </element>
```

My code returns all values correctly (the `name` and `type` attributes) but not `abc:id`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;
use XML::LibXML::XPathContext;

my $filename = '/schema.xml';
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => $filename );

my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new( $dom );
$xpc->registerNs( 'ns', 'abc:http://www.example.com/schemas/abc' );

foreach my $title ( $xpc->findnodes( '//schema' ) ) {

    foreach my $title ( $xpc->findnodes( '//TheType[@name="MyName"]/sequence/element' ) ) {

        say $title->findvalue( './@name' ), '|', $title->findvalue( '??????' ), '|', $title->findvalue( './@type' );
    }
}
```

My thoughts are

- `$xpc->registerNs( 'ns',  'abc:http://www.example.com/schemas/abc' );` is wrong
- Every possibility I tried for the `findvalue` for `abc:id`—where the `????` is in the code—was wrong.

I tried many things here including things like `ns:/@id` to  `*[local-name()="id"]`

Comment: The usage is `$xpc->registerNs('abc',  'http://www.example.com/schemas/abc');`. Then use `abc:id` instead of `id` in the XPaths.

Comment: `ns:/@id` should be `@abc:id` and `*[local-name()="id"]` is looking for an *element* with a local name of `id` and will not match attributes. Within both the XML and the Perl code, a namespace is identified by its URI. In your XML the prefix `abc` stands in for that URI, but you may use another name altogether in your Perl (although it would be wise not to).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[XML::LibXML::XPathContext](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML::XPathContext) doesn't have to be used (in the recent years), it's loaded with [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML).

The correct usage of the `registerNs` function is to give it a prefix and URI.

Using the same variable for a nested loop makes no sense, especially if you don't use the outer variable anywhere.

You can use [join](http://p3rl.org/join) to avoid repeating the call to `findvalue`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw{ say };

use XML::LibXML;

my $filename = shift;
my $dom = 'XML::LibXML'->load_xml(location => $filename);

my $xpc = 'XML::LibXML::XPathContext'->new($dom);
$xpc->registerNs(abc => 'http://www.example.com/schemas/abc');

for my $title ($xpc->findnodes('//TheType[@name="MyName"]/sequence/element')) {
    say join '|', map $title->findvalue($_), '@name', '@abc:id', '@type';
}
```

Comment: Re "*XML::LibXML::XPathContext doesn't have to be used, it's loaded with XML::LibXML.*", That wasn't always the case. Loading it explicitly gives backwards compatibility.

Comment: @ikegami: Thanks, updated. I vaguely remember noticing I can omit the use clause, but I can't find a mention of it in the Changes.

Comment: It changed in 1.70

Comment: Ah, ok, 6 years ago or more :-)

Comment: 8, but still newer than still-used Perl 5.10.

Comment: This change was what I needed.. Thanks. -  `$xpc->registerNs(abc => 'http://www.example.com/schemas/abc');`